# Add dynamic angular attributes to dom element

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, attributes, directive

I have an ApplicationController that runs over my dynamic controller
This Application controller has an array that are my App-bar actions.

Well, every dynamic controller i have inherit the ability to change this array, once its on $scope.headers.actions;

What I'm trying to do right now is to create a directive where i'll be able to add angular attributes (ng-class, ng-if, etc...) dynamically where this attributes definition will come from $scope.headers.actions[...].attributes

Now my directive is:

```
app.directive('ngDynamicAttrs', ['$compile',function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: { list: '=ngDynamicAttrs' },
        //priority: 1001,
        //terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            for (attr in scope.list) {
                attrs.$set(attr, scope.list[attr]);
                //elem[0].setAttribute(attr, scope.list[attr]);
                //elem.attr(attr, scope.list[attr]);
            }
            $compile(elem)(scope);

        }
    };
}]);
```

My html is:

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li class="action" ng-repeat="action in header.actions.pool" ng-click="action.events.click()" ng-dynamic-attrs="action.attributes" id="{{action.id}}">
        <i ng-if="action.icon" class="icon fa {{action.icon}}"></i>
        {{action.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my action object is :

```
$scope.header = {
    actions: {
        pool: [],
        clear: function (actions) {
            $scope.header.actions.pool = [];
        },
        set: function (actions) {
            $scope.header.actions.clear();

            for (i in actions) {
                $scope.header.actions.add(actions[i].id, actions[i].name, actions[i].icon, actions[i].events, actions[i].items, actions[i].attributes)
            }
        },
        add: function (id, name, icon, events, items, attributes) {
            $scope.header.actions.pool.push($scope.header.actions.create(id, name, icon, events, items, attributes));
        },
        remove: function (id) {
            for (i in $scope.header.actions.pool) {
                if ($scope.header.actions.pool[i].id == id) delete $scope.header.actions.pool[i];
            }
        },
        create: function (id, name, icon, events, items, attributes) {
            return { id: id, name: name, icon: icon, events: events, items: items, attributes: attributes };
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not even considering the events right here because it's not a big deal once i can easily use normal dom events.

Comment: WHat is the question? Why do you need all properties as attributes?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got your question but i what i need is to add any angular attribute to that element generated by ng-repeat. I need to do things like 'ng-disabled="formx.$invalid"' .

Comment: why can't you just pass in the whole object instead of creating attribute for each of it's properties?

Comment: I'm not creating attributes for each propertie. I'm creating attribute for each action.attributes item, which means to be an attribute definition it self. See in template action.attributes beeing set to nd-dynamic-attrs value and scope: like='ngDynamicAttrs' as list for my attributes